# MKMap in Xamarin.ios: Always shows the same location in Africa

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm using the MKMap. I want the map to initially show the users location. But no matter what change I make in my code for region, the map shows the same location with the same zoom level.

Here is my code.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    map.MapType = MapKit.MKMapType.Standard;
    map.ShowsUserLocation = true;
    var mapCenter = map.UserLocation.Coordinate;
    var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance (mapCenter, 200, 200);
    map.CenterCoordinate = mapCenter;
    map.Region = mapRegion;

    map.DidUpdateUserLocation += (sender, e) => {
        if (map.UserLocation != null){
            mapCenter = map.UserLocation.Coordinate;
            mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.FromDistance (mapCenter, 100, 100);
            map.CenterCoordinate = mapCenter;
            map.Region = mapRegion;
        }
    };

    //add annotation
    map.AddAnnotation (new MKPointAnnotation () {Title = "My Annotation", Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (map.UserLocation.Coordinate.Latitude,map.UserLocation.Coordinate.Longitude)});

    //set map
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

This is my first time working with Xamarin and programming for ios. So I appreciate if u consider not discussing advanced issues when replying.

I'm using Xamarin and c# (not xcode) and testing on virual device iphone 4s ios 8.1.

Thanks a lot before.

Comment: This occurs quite commonly on simulator since xcode 6 have you tested on device?

Comment: No, I don't have a physical device yet.

Comment: I am not sure about the language differences but it is also important to note that Apple changed some things and requires the App user to allow the location settings to work in iOS8 which means you need to implement a `UIAlertView`. Sadly it wont display as an error during runtime and will not show locations. I do not know how to implement in C# but it's worth trying to find the solution.